# Regex text and some tags between tag

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I have problem with regex tag html. Any one please help me!
Thanks this is some case of me... I have search and think but not do it.

## Case 1

```
// My input to regex
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit <br/><a href="#"><img src="img.jpg/></a> sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua<p>

// Out Put after regex    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit <br/><a href="#"><img src="img.jpg/></a> sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

## Case 2

```
// My input to regex
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>

// Out put after regex            
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
```

## Case 3

```
// My input to regex

<p><ul>...</ul><p>

//Out put after regex

NULL
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason?

Comment: I think the problem here is there's no code, and it's completely unclear what or if you're asking a question.

Comment: I want use regex match the tags and get output.

Comment: Why any my question have been -2, or -1 :(

Comment: Because it's hard to understand what exactly it is you're asking, and you don't explain what you've tried so far to solve them yourself.

Comment: I have change my question,i have 3 case and i want regex input to output as expected, please help me!

Comment: A better way to ask this question would be: I want a regex that will match the contents of a P-element, but only if the contents are text or text with html-elements inside them, not when the contents are just one html element. At least that's what I think you're asking, but I can't be sure.

Comment: It good, but i use translate.google.com to question because should be limited

Comment: The problem is not your english, but the fact that those three examples could be interpreted in a number of different ways. You're only likely to get answers if people are sure they fully understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing something like this is what you're after (example in javascript).

```js
function checkParagraph(str)
{
    var result = str.match(/^<p>([^<].*[^>])<\/p>$/i);
    if (result) return result[1];
    else return null;
}

alert(checkParagraph("<p>Lorem ipsum <br/><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"img.jpg\"/></a> magna aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p>Lorem ipsum magna aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"img.jpg\"/></a></p>"));
```

With the additional information about only allowing BR, IMG, A and IMG-inside-A tags, the regex is quite different:

```js
function checkParagraph(str)
{
    var result = str.match(/^<p>(([^<>]+|<br\/>|<img[^>]+>|<a[^>]+>[^<>]*<\/a>|<a[^>]+><img[^>]+><\/a>)*)<\/p>$/i);
    if (result) return result[1];
    else return null;
}

alert(checkParagraph("Lorem ipsum magna aliqua"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p>Lorem ipsum magna aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p>Lorem ipsum <br/> magna aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p>Lorem ipsum <a href=\"#\">magna</a> aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p>Lorem ipsum <img src=\"img.jpg\"/> magna aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p>Lorem ipsum <br/><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"img.jpg\"/></a> magna aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p><br/><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"img.jpg\"/></a></p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p><span>magna</span> aliqua</p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p><a href=\"#\"><span>magna</span> aliqua</a></p>"));
alert(checkParagraph("<p><br/><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"img.jpg\"/><span>magna</span> aliqua</a></p>"));
```

Break-down of the regex:

`/.../i` -> case insensitive for upper and lower case tags
`^<p>...<\/p>$` -> input is enclosed in P tag
`(...)` -> the capture group between the brackets will become result[1]
`(...|...)*` -> any number of the following options:
`[^<>]+` -> option 1: any text without tags
`<br\/>` -> option 2: a BR tag
`<img[^>]+>` -> option 3: an IMG tag
`<a[^>]+>[^<>]*<\/a>` -> option 4: an A tag with text inside
`<a[^>]+><img[^>]+><\/a>` -> option 5: an A tag with an IMG tag inside

Comment: This good, but i want only tags <a><img><br> in tag <p> is accepted, rest return null

Comment: That was the explanation that was missing from your question. It's always best to both give some examples and describe in words exactly what the desired result is.

Comment: I thought my sub-questions will not be answered, but I was wrong! You have pro and good man, this very perfect for me.. Thanks you alot !!!